# How to connect Firebase to Google Apps Script in 2022?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-apps-script, firebase-realtime-database

I want to connect my (running) Google Apps Script web app to Firebase.
It is for now connected to spreadsheets and pulls data from there, but I thought connecting it to Firebase would be a great thing for the future, also authentication-wise.

How to properly set the connection from Firebase to GAS?

What I have done so far:

- Create a firebase account, and create a realtime database
- Register my app

In this page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup they explain how to connect it to a web-app javascript, by installing NPM SDK etc.

But when I go to app scripts/libraries, nothing like Firebase exists.
And I don't get what this line means:

```
npm install firebase
```

It is like the explanation doesn't match what I see. I thought maybe because Firebase is a google product the installation is easier but then what exactly should I do?